# Flyback converter simulation in LTspice: discrepancy between Switching model and Averaged Switch model

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, spice

I´m trying to make a Averaged Switch Model of a flyback converter for transient and AC simulation in LTspice. I´m following the document "Advances in Averaged Switch Modeling and Simulation" by D. Maksimovic and R. Erickson (link: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?epid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=f24c52ed6d74be1869d628ddff8355063f5ea0c2). I´ve tried the direct implementation of the model given in page 87 with no success, then i moved into creating the circuit of page 86 in LTspice. The circuit seems to work at some degree but is evident there is a mistake somewhere because the start up simulation of the switching model and the averaged model doesnt match (there is also a transient in steady state of the response of the averaged model that, being the load, input voltage and duty cicle all fixed, makes no sense to me)

My question is: Is there any obvious mistake causing the mismatch between the responses that i´m no seeing?

I´m attaching the simulation result of the output voltage of both, the averaged model and the switched one together with a capture of the LTspice implementation of the averaged model and a link to the LTspice file.

[image: LTspice averaged model for DCM and CCM simulation]

[image: Simulation results of the output voltage]

Link to the Ltspice file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U4IdalaydUeYP4bBveGnAU0PpLkU3H9C/view?usp=sharing

Update:

1. I found that the simulated response is heavily influenced by the 'Reltol' parameter in SPICE; lower values of Reltol make the simulated variables discontinuous.
2. I think that the problem is related to the operation in DCM mode.

3.I found that replacing the transformer model (B1, B2, R12, R13, R14, and VM) with coupled inductors makes the simulation fail during DCM operation.

Comment: Luciano C - Hi, Avoiding duplication / overlap between questions is always a good idea, unless it can be clearly justified (which is very rare). FYI, on Stack Exchange the correct etiquette is usually to edit a question to clarify / improve it e.g. in response to comments (unless it has received an answer and the change would invalidate the answer). Posting a new, slightly-updated question is therefore typically not needed, and can cause issues, especially if there were useful comments on a now-deleted old version which are still relevant, but are now "lost". Try to stick with this version. TY

Comment: Is there supposed to be a connection to s_avg? Otherwise B1 seems to be only producing useless common-mode voltage and I(VM) ~= 0. Afraid I don't use cycle-averaged models so I can't comment further on the formulas. [I don't see that this change has been addressed specifically, therefore copying my comment from prev]

Comment: @TimWilliams I added the connection from ground to 's_avg' because I found out that leaving 's_avg' open results in some discontinuities in the output voltage response. I'm not sure if it was the right thing to do; perhaps the discontinuities were caused by another problem; Nevertheless, I couldn't eliminate those discontinuities with any of the simulation configuration I've tested.

Comment: 0.1T is not a connection to ground; it might well pass less current than ABSTOL and therefore be ignored entirely. Likewise R14 seems dimensioned to avoid affecting the solution, though it's at least small enough to have some numerical relevance. A path to ground from the isolated side *is required* but only to avoid a *singular matrix* condition.

Comment: I think you are almost there but when I tested averaged versus cycle-by-cycle models - I did it with the PWM switch and the CoPEC models in my 2014 [book](https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Mode-Power-Supplies-Second-Edition/dp/0071823468/ref=dp_ob_image_bk) - I was first using the simplest possible buck converter with one output capacitor, a perfect diode and that was all for comparing waveforms. When this was ok, I was trying other structures but the idea is to keep implementations on both sides (AVG and TRAN) at the lowest working level (why so many output caps for a simple test?).

Comment: @TimWilliams , you're right, 0.1T isn't a connection at all. I was trying to say that I added a connection through R17 to ground. R14 is there because, at first, I had some problems with the output going infinite; later, I realized a labeling mistake but didn't delete R14 because I didn't see any difference if either was present or not.

Comment: @VerbalKint Hi Chris, I have some of your books; they're an amazing piece of work and have been really helpful for many things I've done. I haven't gotten that particular book yet, and I don't recall seeing those "CoPEC" models you mentioned. Regarding the output capacitors, I just started working from an old LTspice flyback converter model.

Comment: @LucianoC, hello, I looked a variety of models in these publications and CoPEC's were inside. However, I found easier to implement the PWM switch model for exploring many more structures like boundary mode, COT, FOT etc. You may find interesting information in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348150883_A_Unified_PWM_Switch_Model_for_Current-and_Voltage-Mode_Control_with_Automatic_Transition_between_DCM_and_CCM) where the author tried to synthesize my auto-toggling models in one single subcircuit. It includes numerous LTspice simulations.